# Appcelerator App Designer assets path issue and RGBA

Tags: ios, iphone, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have an issue with Appcelerator App Designer.
I have an image path in assets like `app/assets/iphone/images/MainBG.png`
In xml i need to use path like `/images/MainBG.png`
But App Designer set path like `/iphone/images/MainBG.png` that does not work when i run my app... Yes, i can change this path, but after that i cant see image in App Designer view.

And second question:
App Designer cant use alpha... Yes, i can manualy set `BGcolor` like `rgba(150,0,0,0.5)` but in App Designer view i cant see result.

Can any one help me?
Sorry for my English))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I have not used App Designer, but following might help you:

- put all your image files in app/assets/images folder
- now set path in XML like image='/images/MainBG.png'

Set background color manually, you can use following combos:

- you can use **backgroundColor:"#fff"**
- also you can use **backgroundColor:"#ffffff"**
- this one also works **backgroundColor:"white"**
- this one works for alpha - **backgroundColor:"#abcd"**, in this syntax, alpha will be **'aa'** & r/g/b will be **bb/cc/dd**.
- so this one will also work for alpha - **backgroundColor:"#aabbccdd"**, 2 digits for each alpha/red/green/blue

Comment: Yes, this is all work. But not in App Designer... For alpha - i use this "combos", they are working on device, but in App Designer view i cant see result...
UPD: Image path issue resolved! Thx!

Comment: May be it's an issue in App Designer. Someone who uses App Designer will be able to help you. Till then, stick to manual code.